# What is the difference between cudaExternalMemoryHandleTypeD3D12Resource and cudaExternalMemoryHandleTypeD3D12Heap?

Tags: resource-management, directx12, cuda

When we import a D3D12 memory object into cuda we do something like this:

```
cudaExternalMemoryHandleDesc cuExtmemHandleDesc{};
cuExtmemHandleDesc.type = cudaExternalMemoryHandleTypeD3D12Resource; //here
//...
CheckCudaErrors(cudaImportExternalMemory(&m_externalMemory, &cuExtmemHandleDesc));
```

What is the difference between `cudaExternalMemoryHandleTypeD3D12Resource` and `cudaExternalMemoryHandleTypeD3D12Heap`? When should I use one or the other when importing memory object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`cudeExternalMemoryHandleTypeD3D12Heap`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__TYPES.html) refers to a [D3D12 heap](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12/nn-d3d12-id3d12heap) object, whereas [`cudeExternalMemoryHandleTypeD3D12Resource`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__TYPES.html) refers to a [D3D12 resource](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12/nn-d3d12-id3d12resource) object. You'd choose the value that correctly represents the D3D12 object type you're referencing via `cudaImportExternalMemory`.

An `ID2D12Heap` is a representation of a contiguous allocation of memory, whereas an `ID3D12Resource` is somewhat higher-level, providing methods for (per the docs)

> organizing and manipulating simple arrays of data as well as multidimensional data optimized for shader sampling